# Compare sound on prerecorded audio file to microphone input

Tags: audio

I am looking into an interesting project where I have to compare the sound on a prerecorded audio file to one that is inputed through a microphone.

Unfortunately, I do not even know where to start. Any feedback, pointers, constructive thoughts are highly appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to compare?

Comment: I'm afraid nobody would know where to start. You can have anything "prerecorded". You can have anything captured "through the microphone". What makes you think that the technical fact of merely having something prerecorded would make a difference? Can you please try to rephrase your question into something that can be technically understandable? Else, I'm afraid your question would be perceived too broad for this format.

Comment: Requirement:Create a program which can compare a 10-15 second audio sound input through a microphone, both from the computer and phone, to a preexisting one. The major impediment that I foresee as a problem will be the microphone quality, because I have no idea of the capabilities. It is also important that the platform is somewhat simple, which I understand will come with time. My ultimate question is "can you create a program to compare a prerecorded audio file to one that is inputed through a microphone? And if so, we must determine the most effective metrics by which to compare the sounds.